# Sort enum list by one of its values using for loops, not sort or compareto

Tags: java, enums, bubble-sort

So, I want to sort, for example, an enum list like this:

public enum SoccerPositions {

```
Striker ("Most advance player in field", 'S'),
MIDFIELDER ("Organizes the game", 'M'),
DEFENDER ("Stops the striker", 'D'),

private final String description; //first field
private final char code; // second field

SoccerPositions (String description, char code) {

    this.description = description;
    this.code = code;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public char getCode() {
    return code;
}


public static SoccerPositions[] getSoccerPositionsSortedbyCode() {

return ;

}
```

}

I tried

```
public static SoccerPositions[] getSoccerPositionsSortedbyCode() {

    SoccerPositions[] soccerPositionsSorted = SoccerPositions.values();

  for (int i = 0; i < SoccerPositions.values().length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (SoccerPositions.values().length - 1 - i); j++) {

            if (SoccerPositions.valueOf()[j] > SoccerPositions.valueOf()[j+1]) {
                int aux = SoccerPositions.valueOf()[j];
                SoccerPositions.valueOf()[j] = SoccerPositions.valueOf()[j+1];
                SoccerPositions.valueOf()[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SoccerPositions.values().length; i++) {

      SoccerPositionsSorted[i] = SoccerPositions.values()[i];
  }

        return soccerPositionsSorted;
```

}

Of courrse, it does not work. I am very new to programming...

I know I could go other ways but I need to do this using a bubble-sort type of way.

Thank you all.

Comment: You should be a lot more specific than just saying "it doesn't work". Like, does your code even compile? Does it run without an error? Does it produce a result?

Comment: It does not compile, I don-t know how to access the code field of the enum list and compare it to the next one using for loops. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your post to show the compiler error, and then post here in the comments once that is completed